# ¿Como solucionar un error en rootsolve?

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy tratando de poner esta función pero me arroja este error, ¿alguien sabe cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```
install.packages("rootSolve")
suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(library(rootSolve)))

g = function(miu) 1/n * sum(log(y))

miu_gorrito = uniroot(f = g, interval = c(0.001,30))
uniroot(f = g)
```

y me arroja este error:

> Error in uniroot(f = g, interval = c(0.001, 30)) : f() values at end points not of opposite sign

Comment: Bienvenido, lo primero de todo re recomiendo que accedas al recorrido (https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ganar tu primera medalla y sepas darle formato a tus preguntas y otras cosas de utilidad. No es el motivo de tu error, pero tienes que definir `n` e `y` para que tu código se ejecute sin error. También te recomiendo que amplíes la amplitud del intervalo.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo muy claro qué es lo que pretendes hacer, imagino que encontrar las raíces de la función `g` empleando la función `uniroot()`. Este código al menos no da error, pero al no saber cuál es el contenido del vector `y` (supongo que es un vector porque lo incluyes en el `sum()`) lo he definido dándole unos valores cualquiera `c(1,1,1)`; también supongo que n es un tamaño muestral y le doy el valor 100.

```
y=c(1,1,1)
n=100
g = function(miu) 1/100 * sum(log(y))

miu_gorrito = uniroot(f = g, interval = c(0.001,100))
miu_gorrito
```

Como te dije en el comentario, debes definir previamente`y` y `n`. Además, el error se te genera porque vuelves a llamar a la función `uniroot()` sin incluir el parámetro "interval" y no comprendo muy bien porqué lo haces, supongo que tu objetivo es que aparezca el resultado de `miu_gorrito` pero te has confundido al no llamarlo una vez creado y vuelves a intentar ejecutar la función `uniroot()`.

Comment: El problema es el siguiente: me toco generar una muestra aleatoria de una población Log-norrmal con un tamaño de muestra de 20 (cosa que ya hice)
al hacer sum de y estoy sumando todos los valores del vecor generado, n lo tengo como 20 pero al momento de ejecutar el coddigo : "g = function(miu) 1/n * sum(log(y))

miu_gorrito = uniroot(f = g, interval = c(0.011, 30))" me sale el siguiente problema 


Error in uniroot(f = g, interval = c(0.001, 30)) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign

¿como podria solucionarlo?